# Microsoft Graphs get SharePoint DriveItems

Tags: c#

This is code to get ListItems from SharePoint:

Microsoft.Graph.Models.ListItemCollectionResponse
itemsInFirstListInFirstSite = await GraphClient.Sites[foundSiteId].Lists[foundListInFirstSite.Id].Items.GetAsync();

But to distinguish, is item file or folder, need to get DriveItems;

What code could be used to fetch DriveItems ?

Thank you in advanced.